# ENC28J60 returning wrong (unexpected) values

Tags: avr, ethernet

I'm trying to create my own library for the ENC28J60. Yes, I know that there are several ready to use libraries out there, but I like to do thing from scratch, so I understand what is going on, how it works.

So, I'm only at the beging and already found  someting that I don't understand.
My first test was to send the RCR command to read BANK0. I've recived mixed results.
Over UART(HyperTerminal) I'm getting the following results back:

```
USART Ready
SPI Ready
1 RCR-ERDPTL Send: 0 "(sending RCR|ERDPTL = 0 over SPI)"
0   11111010    11111010    OK   
1   101         101         OK
2   0           0           OK
3   0           0           OK
4   0           0           OK
5   0           0           OK
6   0           0           OK
7   0           0           OK
8   1000        11111010    ERROR
9   101         101         OK
10  11111111    11111111    OK
11  11111       11111       OK
12  110001      11111010    ERROR
13  110011      101         ERROR
14  0           0           OK
15  0           0           OK
```

The first column is the byte number or the number of the register of BANK0,
The second column is the value that I'm getting from the ENC chip(according to the datasheet),
The third is tha value I should get,
And the fouth is just a simple check to find a mismatch.

As you can see there are 3 values that do not correspond with the datasheet.
Why?

My code is the following:

```
#include <define.h>
#include <ENC28J60.h>

#define ENC28J60        PB3
#define ENC28J61        PB4
#define DUMMY           0x00
unsigned char i, data, data0[] = {}, data1[] = {}, data2[] = {}, 
data3[16] = {0b11111010, 0b00000101, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0b11111010,0b00000101,255,0b00011111,0b11111010,0b00000101,0,0};


void ENC28J60_CS(void)              // ENC28J60 Select
{
    SPI_PORT &= ~(1<<ENC28J60);
}

void ENC28J60_DS(void)              // ENC28J60 DeSelect
{
    SPI_PORT |= (1<<ENC28J60);
}

void ENC28J61_CS(void)              // ENC28J60 Select
{
    SPI_PORT &= ~(1<<ENC28J61);
}

void ENC28J61_DS(void)              // ENC28J60 DeSelect
{
    SPI_PORT |= (1<<ENC28J61);
}

void ENC28J60_SRC(void)             // System Reset Command (Soft Reset) 
{
    ENC28J60_CS();                  // Enable
    SPIWR(0xFF);
    ENC28J60_DS();                  // Disable
    _delay_ms(50);
}

int main(void)
{
_delay_ms(3000);
USART0_Init(12);
USART0_TX_String("USART Ready");
USART0_TXD(10);                     
USART0_TXD(13);

SPI_Init();
PORTB ^= 1<<PINB0;
USART0_TX_String("SPI Ready");
USART0_TXD(10);                     
USART0_TXD(13);

ENC28J60_DS();
ENC28J61_DS();
_delay_ms(250);

ENC28J60_SRC();
ENC28J61_CS();                  // Enable
SPIWR(0xFF);
ENC28J61_DS();                  // Disable
_delay_ms(250);

ENC28J60_CS();
SPIWR(RCR|ERDPTL);
PORTB ^= 1<<PINB0;
USART0_TX_String("1 RCR-ERDPTL Send: ");
itoa(RCR|ERDPTL, StringA, 10);
USART0_TX_String(StringA);
USART0_TXD(10);                     
USART0_TXD(13);
data = SPIWRD(0xFF);

for(i = 0;i<15;i++)
{
    data0[i] = SPIWRD(0xFF);
}

ENC28J60_DS();


for(i = 0;i<16;i++)
{
    PORTB ^= 1<<PINB0;
    itoa(i, StringA, 10);
    USART0_TX_String(StringA);
    USART0_TXD(9);

    itoa(data0[i], StringA, 2);
    USART0_TX_String(StringA);
    USART0_TXD(9);
    USART0_TXD(9);

    itoa(data3[i], StringA, 2);
    USART0_TX_String(StringA);
    USART0_TXD(9);

    if(data0[i] == data3[i])
    {
        USART0_TX_String("OK");
    }
    else
    {
        USART0_TX_String("ERROR");
    }

    USART0_TXD(10);                     
    USART0_TXD(13);
}

PORTB |= 1<<PINB0;

    while(1)
    {

    }
}
```

There is another matter that gives me headaches.
I ha to add an extra SPI junk transmission on line 71, because if I had not done this, I would get the first result twice and so the rest would get out of line. 
According to the datasheet(section 4.2.1) only by reading from the MAC or MII registers should I get a dummy byte.
What's up whit that?

I'm using AVR ATMega1284P with WinAVR.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the problem is yet again in the code.

In the declaration of my variables(data0 to 2) I have not set the size of them:

```
unsigned char i, data, data0[] = {}, data1[] = {}, data2[] = {}, 
data3[16] = {0b11111010, 0b00000101,0,0,0,0,0,0,0b11111010,0b00000101,
255,0b00011111,0b11111010,0b00000101,0,0};
```

I should have done this:

```
unsigned char i, data, data0[16] = {}, data1[16] = {}, data2[16] = {}, 
data3[16] = {0b11111010, 0b00000101, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0b11111010,0b00000101,
255,0b00011111,0b11111010,0b00000101,0,0};
```

Comment: Hello, I'm trying to do a project similar to yours. I want to Simulate the ENC28J60 in Proteus,how can i do it??

Comment: Hello!
Sorry, can't help you with the simulation. I've stopped using Proteus after I've run some C++ codes(inculdeing ones with the ENC28J60 chip), that worked form me on the actual hardware, but the simulation crashed or recieved trash data.

Comment: @GiridharKarnik if you have a question different from the one here, ask it as a new one.